# While reading from socket how to detect when the client is done sending the request?

Tags: java, sockets, httprequest, httpserver

I am now writing a http server and I am having problem with reading from a socket.
My problem is that the `inputStream` from the client never ends and it keeps reading until the client is closed.
I know that the client doesn't close the connection with the server immediately after sending the http request.
How can I quit the `while loop` when client has sent all the request data (i.e. headers + body).

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = in.nextLine();

    if (line.equals("")){ // last line of request header is blank
        break; // quit while loop when last line of header is reached
    } else {
        request = request + line + "\n";
    }
}
```

After reading comments and answer from you guys, this is what I came up with,

```
     is = incoming.getInputStream();
            os = incoming.getOutputStream();
            in = new Scanner(is);
            out = new DataOutputStream(os);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            int length = 0;
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                if (line.equals("")) { // last line of request message
                                        // header is a
                                        // blank line
                    break; // quit while loop when last line of header is
                            // reached
                }

                if (line.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) { // get the
                                                            // content-length
                    int index = line.indexOf(':') + 1;
                    String len = line.substring(index).trim();
                    length = Integer.parseInt(len);
                }

                request = request + line + "\n";
            }

             byte[] body = new byte[length];
             int i = 0;
             while (i < length) {
             byte b = in.nextByte();
             body[i] = b;
             i++;
             }
```

but, I still don't get it about reading by bytes. I can write my code to read until -1, but still stuck when there is no EOF and client is not closing connection.

Comment: If it's a `GET`, you can stop after you get `\r\n\r\n`, if it has request body, you can stop after `Content-Length` bytes are read from the request body.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Comment: Scanner.nextByte() does parsing according to the prevailing radix; it doesn't return a raw byte. You should be using a `DataInputStream` for this. And yes I know its `readLine()` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it :) Thank you guys for comments and answers...

```
     is = incoming.getInputStream(); // initiating inputStream
            os = incoming.getOutputStream(); // initiating outputStream

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); // initiating
                                                                // bufferReader
            out = new DataOutputStream(os); // initiating DataOutputSteream

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler(); // create a
                                                        // requestHandler
                                                        // object

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals("")) { // last line of request message
                                        // header is a
                                        // blank line (\r\n\r\n)
                    break; // quit while loop when last line of header is
                            // reached
                }

                // checking line if it has information about Content-Length
                // weather it has message body or not
                if (line.startsWith("Content-Length: ")) { // get the
                                                            // content-length
                    int index = line.indexOf(':') + 1;
                    String len = line.substring(index).trim();
                    length = Integer.parseInt(len);
                }

                request.append(line + "\n"); // append the request
            } // end of while to read headers

            // if there is Message body, go in to this loop
            if (length > 0) {
                int read;
                while ((read = in.read()) != -1) {
                    body.append((char) read);
                    if (body.length() == length)
                        break;
                }
            }

            request.append(body); // adding the body to request
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 ways of detecting the end of the stream depending on what requests you are handling:

1. If it is a `GET` or `HEAD` request, you only need to read the HTTP headers, request body is normally ignored if it exists, so when you encounter `\r\n\r\n`, you reach the end of the request(actually the request headers).
2. If it is a `POST` method, read the `Content-Length` in the header and read up to `Content-Length` bytes.
3. If it is a `POST` method and the `Content-Length` header is absent, which is most likely to happen, read until `-1` is returned, which is the signal of `EOF`.

Comment: Omit (1) and use (2) and (3) only, for all methods, including GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, DELETE, ... If the client is doing keepalive you have to read to the end of all requests, otherwise you won't get the next one correctly.

Comment: Hi, @EJP, thanks for mentioning `keepalive`. If `Content-Length` is absent, how do I detect the end of the request if the client is doing `keepalive`?

Comment: It's not a legal situation. If the client is doing keep-alive he must send a content-length, as you state yourself in (3).

Comment: Most non-`GET`/`HEAD` requests can have a message body, so limiting #2 and #3 to just `POST` is wrong. Also, "*If the client is doing keep-alive he must send a content-length*"  is not true, either.`Content-Length` is optional if `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or `Content-Type: multipart/...` is used instead. And reading until `EOF` is not valid for requests, only for responses. Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 "Message Length"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for the exact rules you need to follow to detect end-of-message in all scenarios, whether keep-alive is used or not.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my code that works great:

```
private static String getClientRequest(Socket client) throws IOException, SocketException {
    System.out.println("Debug: got new client " + client.toString());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

    StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    int contectLegnth = 0;
    
    while (!(line = br.readLine()).isBlank()) {
        requestBuilder.append(line + "\r\n");
        if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("content-length")) {
            contectLegnth = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1].trim());
        }
    }
    

    StringBuilder requestBodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (contectLegnth > 0) {
        int read;
        while ((read = br.read()) != -1) {
            requestBodyBuilder.append((char) read);
            if (requestBodyBuilder.length() == contectLegnth)
                break;
        }
        requestBuilder.append("\r\n" + requestBodyBuilder);
    }
   
    return requestBuilder.toString();
}
```