# Java, HTTP, & Sockets: When to stop reading the request but keep the socket open?

Tags: java, sockets, http

My team is building a basic HTTP server from scratch in Java, but our reader threads block once they run out of request text to read from the socket's input stream. 
A number of points unique to our situation that don't match up with [questions asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353592/while-reading-from-socket-how-to-detect-when-the-client-is-done-sending-the-requ):

- We want to keep the socket open while we process the request and produce a response to send back
- We don't parse the data at first, but rather, we first read it off the socket and chuck the entire thing into a recovery file. Then we begin to parse and validate from the file, to ensure that we don't lose the request in case of disaster.

The basic code:

```
public void readSocket() {
    receivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    requestFile = new File("recovery/" + receivedTime + ".txt");
    try(
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(requestFile);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
    )
    {
        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){ //TODO: this is where it blocks after reading past the last line of the request. 
            out.write(line);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use Java's own [HttpServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) class instead?  And why cache the request for disaster recovery?  If something goes wrong, the client is gone anyway, so you can't send a response back, so why recovery at all?  HTTP is meant to be stateless.  Make the client reconnect and send the request again.

Comment: The project spec demands that we build our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readLine()` returns `null` only if "the end of the stream has been reached", ie the socket has been closed by the other party.  When `readLine()` reads a line break with no preceding data, it returns a non-null `String` that has a `length` of 0.  So you need to fix you `while` loop accordingly:

```
public void readSocket() {
    receivedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    requestFile = new File("recovery/" + receivedTime + ".txt");
    try(
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(requestFile);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
    )
    {
        String line;

        // read request headers...
        do {
            line = in.readLine();

            if (line == null) return; // socket closed

            out.write(line);
            out.NewLine();
            out.flush();

            if (line.isEmpty()) break; // end of headers reached

            // process line as needed...
        }
        while (true);

        // check received headers for presence of a message
        // body, and read it if needed. Refer to RFC 2616
        // Section 4.4 for details...

        // process request as needed...

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also see:

[While reading from socket how to detect when the client is done sending the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353592/)

Comment: Actually, that's true, but it won't work for requests that have payloads. Seemingly, I would have to parse out the HTTPMethod right away and figure out if it should break on the empty line or wait until after the payload, which also requires parsing out the content-length header.

Comment: @MDjava that all falls under the "*check received headers for presence of a message body, and read it if needed*" placeholder in my example.